# After installing extension on server it gives 404 error?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

Magento 1.9.1.0
I have created an extension that store some information from user. It's working fine on my localhost. When i install this extension on server(192.xxx.xxx.xxx/mysite) its frondend working fine. but listing of information on backend gives 404 error.

Comment: Is this a full page 404 error or just in plugin section.

Comment: If it is in plugin section then you need logout from your account and login again will resolve the issue, one more thing don't forget to reindex and clear you magento caches.

Comment: its full page 404 error. Whoops, our bad...

The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.

        If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
        If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.

What can you do?
    Have no fear, help is near! There are many ways you can get back on track with Magento Store.

        Go back to the previous page.
        Use the search bar at the top of the page to search for your products.
        Follow these links to get you back on track!

Comment: Any hardcoded values.You need to debug router code as that will lead to the reason.

Comment: Satish its working fine on localhot.

Comment: I have the same issue, i solved this issue by delete and reinstall the  tables used in plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to the permission of your installed app and admin, login to your Magento admin back-end, take System-> Permissions->Users, it will list out the users in the system. click on the admin, it will open in edit mode and save it, then it will ask current admin password. then check your extension.

Comment: Then some files you missed to copy in to the server, please check that also